# Querying in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

In SQL we have partion by and group by

```
select deptno, count(*) c from emp group by deptno;

DEPTNO C
------ -
10     3
20     5
30     6

select deptno, count(*) over (partition by deptno) c from emp;


DEPTNO C
------ -
10     3
10     3
10     3
20     5
20     5
20     5
20     5
20     5
30     6
30     6
30     6
30     6
30     6
30     6
```

If we need to practice the same thing in HIVE what will be the option .
Do we have the same in Hive?
Pls suggest

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hive supports windowing functions, see [Windowing and Analytics Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics). So is really exactly as you posted:

```
select deptno, count(*) over (partition by deptno) c from emp;
```

The trick is that you need to be on a Hive that is recent enough to have the windowing functions. The linked page shows these were introduced in Hive 0.11.

As for the first query `select deptno, count(*) c from emp group by deptno;` that is just an ordinary aggregate, I think was supported in v. -1 ...

Answer (score 0):

same problem ..

I tried Windowing and Analytics Functions. .

FAILED: ParseException line 1:29 missing FROM at '(' near '(' in subquery source
line 1:30 cannot recognize input near 'PARTITION' 'BY' 'salary' in subquery source